# Kafka SSL connectivity with PEM file, Kafka and JDBC connector

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, postman

I am trying to use the directory path of the .pem certificate file in linux on Apache Kafka JDBCconnector using RestClient(by passing in postgresql cloud connection string) . Can we pass .pem certs directory path in linux on Rest client directly without storing in keystore?